# My new manager does not care about employee's well-being

Tags: manager, micro-management

My new manager has taken over the team, where their management style is very authoritarian.

When having a career conversation with her they just mentioned that it is their way of the highway, to the point that she is changing people’s roles and telling them to perform roles that they are not trained in.

Seven people have left the org since they’ve taken over, I’m not sure what to do now.

Advice?

Comment: Look for a new job? 7 people seems a lot, the manager does not seem to be there to make friends or keep employees.

Comment: Can you try to get transferred to another team ? If not, sometimes, if you wait for long enough (a few years), then a new and reasonable manager may take over the team. Otherwise, it may be best to start looking for a new job, and you may find a better one with a higher salary and a better manager.

Answer (score 5):

> Seven people have left the org since they’ve taken over,

That's a in most cases a serious. You have three choices

1. Find a new job
2. Suck it up and accept the situation as is
3. Elevate to the manager's manager

Whether the last option is reasonable depends on your environment & culture. Normally a manager causing a mass exodus will generate some attention and scrutiny. However if the manager is still producing results and the company doesn't care how results are generated, you have a little or no chance of changing that.